# Customizing jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

For learning jQuery UI dialog, I have the code defined below.

I need to do following three tasks

1) Use my image as “OK” button and “Cancel” button

2) Use my custom image as the close button on right top end of dialog

3) Background of the whole dialog should be “gray” (including title, and place for OK button.)

The important point is the style should be applied only to my dialog. All other widgets should have default behavior. For content area, I could achieve it using #myDiv.ui-widget-content.

Can you please suggest code for this?

Note: Please use the best practices, if possible. (E.g. 1.  use a variable $myDialog 2. use autoOpen: false)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title> </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" />


     <link href="Styles/OverrideMyDialog.css" rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" />-



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $myDialog = $(".addNewDiv").dialog(
                                    {
                                        autoOpen: false,
                                        title: 'My Title',
                                        buttons: { "OK": function () {
                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                            ShowAlert();
                                            return true;
                                        },
                                            "Cancel": function () {
                                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                           );





        $('#myOpener').click(function () {
            return $myDialog.dialog('open');


        });
    });

    function ShowAlert() {
        alert('OK Pressed');
    }

</script>
```

```
<body>
    <div>
    <input id="myOpener" type="button" value="button" />
</div>
<div class="addNewDiv"  id="myDiv" title="Add new Person" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Age
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I made a css class to override the widget functionality only for my dialog

```
    /*
   *File Name: OverrideMyDialog.css
   * jQuery UI CSS is overriden here for one div
  */


/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/

#myDiv.ui-widget-content 
{ 
border: 5px solid Red;
background: Gray url(images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png) 50% bottom repeat-x;
color: Green; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have upvoted the above answer. Still **dialogClass**: 'myDialogCSS' was the key I was looking for.

**HTML and jQuery**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-
    1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/themes/Sunny/jqueryui.
    css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/MyStyleSheet.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $myDialog = $(".addNewDiv").dialog(
            {
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                dialogClass: 'myDialogCSS',
                title: 'My Title',
                closeOnEscape: false,
                open: function(event, ui)
                {
                    //Disable OK Button
                    $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane
                        button:contains('OK')").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                },
                buttons: { "OK": function ()
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    ShowAlert();
                    return true;
                },
                    "Cancel": function ()
                    {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            );
            $('#myOpener').click(function ()
            {
                return $myDialog.dialog('open');
            });
        });
        function ShowAlert() {
            alert('OK Pressed');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input id="myOpener" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
    <div class="addNewDiv" id="myDiv" title="Add new Person">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyStyleSheet.css**

```
   /*Title Bar*/
   .myDialogCSS .ui-dialog-titlebar
     {
       /*Hide Title Bar*/
       /*display:none; */
     }

   /*Content*/
   .myDialogCSS .ui-dialog-content
     {
       font-size:30px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should customize the css file. class are:

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar { padding: .4em 1em; position: relative;  }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title { float: left; margin: .1em 16px .1em 0; } 
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { position: absolute; right: .3em; top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 18px; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close span { display: block; margin: 1px; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover, .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:focus { padding: 0; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { position: relative; border: 0; padding: .5em 1em; background: none; overflow: auto; zoom: 1; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { text-align: left; border-width: 1px 0 0 0; background-image: none; margin: .5em 0 0 0; padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { float: right; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button { margin: .5em .4em .5em 0; cursor: pointer; }
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se { width: 14px; height: 14px; right: 3px; bottom: 3px; }
.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar { cursor: move; }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample (like where to apply this and how)?

Comment: That's for the tabs, not the dialog

Comment: you can find this in jquery-ui.css file

Comment: @Lijo, check my answer. You might need to put `!important` if anything doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For this you will have to over-ride default css provided by jQuery UI (jquery.ui.theme.css).

1. Image for Ok button: You need to change `.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default` background image.
2. Close Button: Change `.ui-widget-header .ui-icon`
3. Background of Dialogue: Change `.ui-widget-content` background property.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Go to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, here you can customize your theme. Download it and play with it. I also did same thing to learn. You can use Firebug (FF), Developer Tools F12 (IE), F12 Chrome to see the css applied to item. Using this tool only I have found the above elements. Hope this works.

Comment: Also if you satisfied with answer, please accept it. Secondly if you need any help, post a comment.

Comment: eg in my case, theme.css has this class `.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default` and here there is one property `background` with some value. You remove this value and put your own image like this `url("images/yourimage.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #0E6D38`. Copy your image to `images` folder inside the theme folder. Inside theme.css search directly for the terms I have provided, and change the `background` property.

Comment: Thanks. The important point is the style should be applied only to my dialog. All other widgets should have default behavior. For content area, I could achieve it using #myDiv.ui-widget-content. How do I achieve other requirements mentioned in the post?

Comment: You can do the same stuff to others too. You can have your own custom CSS file in which you override the defaults provided by jQuery. In that case in this CSS file, you will have `#myDiv.ui-widget-content`, `#myDiv.ui-widget-header .ui-icon` etc. Also if your values donesn't reflect, put `!important` eg `background-color: red !important`.